# How to update a huge MySQL table from a text file

Tags: mysql, update, import

I have a huge MySQL table with 1.3 TB data with InnoDB engine format.

Now I have a text file containing updated values of 2.2 GB of records in the 1.3 TB of data.

How do I proceed ?

I am a newbie to this data loading part. Please guide me through this.

Here the sample data present in the .txt file.

```
91653   8       2       1       4       Publisher                               2       1       4
91653   8       2       2       5       Publisher                               3b      1       5
```

Comment: whats exactly in the text file command for update (update table set ...) just the data?

Comment: its just the data to be loaded. and it is stored in TSV (Tab Separated Values) format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `TSV` file you can use the following command to import the data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.tsv' INTO TABLE database_name.my_table;
```

references:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/importing-tab-separated-file-tsv-table-853669.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: How to handle the schema in this scenario. I think the schemas of both TSV and table should match is it ?

Comment: the TSV table you export in MySQL contain the column name and values, so the columns should be matched in name and value type in-order to import